# Are songs without musical instruments haraam?

Tags: halal-haram, music

I know singing with musical instruments is *haraam*. Also songs with words in them that go against the teachings of Islam are also *haraam*. But what about songs without any bad message or any instruments, and those that do not necessarily praise Allah?

I mean, for example, there are songs which reflect the love for one's country, or one's wife. Often times they do not contain any messages that go against Islam, but just contain messages towards something permissible by Islam. Is it allowed to to listen to or sing these songs?

And also, there is a lot of music with instruments and bad words. But what if someone edits the lyrics, cuts out the bad words and sings them without any instruments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Al-Quran 07:32.Say (O Muhammad S.A.W): "Who has forbidden the adoration with clothes given by Allah, which He has produced for his slaves, and At-Taiyibat [all kinds of Halal (lawful) things] of food?" Say: "They are, in the life of this world, for those who believe, (and) exclusively for them (believers) on the Day of Resurrection (the disbelievers will not share them)." Thus We explain the Ayat (Islamic laws) in detail for people who have knowledge.***

**Al-Quran 07:33 Say (O Muhammad S.A.W ): "(But) the things that my Lord has indeed forbidden are Al-Fawahish (great evil sins, every kind of unlawful sexual intercourse, etc.) whether committed openly or secretly, sins (of all kinds), unrighteous oppression, joining partners (in worship) with Allah for which He has given no authority, and saying things about Allah of which you have no knowledge."**

To my mind all songs are not harram, yes the songs which misguide you and makes you deviate from Oness Of Allah subhan-a-tallah and or if there are some or even one word or phrase which is misguidence or keeps you away from Islam or sexual in nature are 100% not alowed/harram and yes majority of songs goes against Islam but not all that's why people say don't listen them. But if song is pure there is nothing against Islam and it's message is allowed. Hazrat Dawood A.S used to sing and birds and animals used to rush towards Hazrat dawood A.s. read the Event of Hazrat Dawood A.S.

I think if you remove bad words from music and sing it for adoration of Allah , He may reward you because deeds are dependable on good intentions. Allah knows best.

Hope You got my point bro if I am mistaken correct me.
Many thanks bro......

Answer (score 1):

Salam alaikom.

Songs with no instruments are just speech. It is like poetry. It depends on their content.

Our messenger (salla allah alaih w sallam) used to love poetry. And it doesn't necessarily need to explicitly praise Allah.

Answer (score 0):

Do not listen to any kinds of music which include instruments as musical insutruments are undoubtedly haram. But Allah has permitted nasheeds and vocals which promote good, Islamic values. A statement from Sheikh Bin Baz states:
Islamic nasheeds differ: if these nasheeds are good and there's nothing in them except calling towards goodness and reminding the people of goodness and also to the obedience of Allah Azzawajal and the Messenger (sallAllahu 'alayhi wa sallam) then there's no problem with this but if it calls towards sins and free mixing between men and women or it calls towards any corruption then this is not permissible - Islamic nasheeds such as poetry; if it's okay then it's okay, if it contains Munkar then it's Munkar. End quote from Sheikh Bin Baz.

Answer (score -1):

Do not play musical instruments it's forbidden, there's a Hadith. Singing is allowed if it dosent go far from ISLAM and have bad content, it's bad if it is offensive to people. The prophet used to let women (men too) sing. Listening to Islamic music (nasheeds) is Halal but listening to swear words and bad content music is """Haram"""". I will research more but from what I know you can listen if it has appropriate content and has a good message. Ask a Shaikh to get a better understanding.

As alam wa alaykum, Bro/Sis.

May Allah forgive us for all our sins, guide us to the right patha no take us to Jannah with the prophets, Inshallah. AMEEN.

Comment: There is also a prophecy saying some time will come when people will listen to Qur'an only for its melody not for meaning...

Answer (score -3):

Music has a brain washing effect.so all music is forbidden even the music that they make with hands and throat.songs that only praise allah brain washes you in a good way.but because humans often cant tell that its evil.so all music was forbidden so shytan doesnt trick you with holy music that leads to normal music.for exsample. You listen to holy music,you son watches you and listens to normal. His son watches him and listens to devil music. 3 generation and your kids are evil.
While music could be a powerfull tool for good. This risk factors are to great.maybe if only imams were permitted to make music it could work.
But there not willing . Lol
May peace be apon you.      Ameer AulSayLomAh ElMahdi